# Proving the Cardinality of Uncountable Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I have been struggling to understand how to prove the cardinality of various sets. I know the definition of two sets 'having the same cardinality' as being the fact that there exists a bijection between the two (or using Cantor-Bernstein Theorem, an injection in both directions).

I however, am unable to follow some of the proofs in lectures. Since I believe them to be quite short, and very similar, I have included them both in this question. And although there may be similar questions already on SE I am asking particular questions about two proofs given in my real analysis lectures.

The proof given (possibly incomplete) as presented in the lecture. I struggle with following the proof and have included various comments explaining my questions in more detail.

> **1. Let $A$ be infinite and $B$ be countable or finite. Then #$(A \cup B)=$#$A.$**

**Proof:** (Possibly incomplete)

Assume union is disjoint. *What precisely does this mean and why may we assume this?*

Then $(A\smallsetminus C )\ \cup C$ is countable. *What is being done here?*

So $(A\smallsetminus C) \ \cup (C\cup B)$.

Then C is countable so we may replace it with $\mathbb N$ WLOG and replace $C$ with even natural numbers and $B$ with odd natural numbers WLOG, and thus there is a bijection from $N$ to $C\cup B$.

*I do not understand this proof at all, unlike most other proofs we have covered. I cannot see how it has proved anything so would be grateful for explanation of this proof, or a statement of a similar proof. I have searched online but have had difficulties finding one.*

> **2. An example following on from (1):** #$[0,1] =$ #$[0,1)$

$[0,1] = [0,1) \cup \{1\}$

$[0,1] = ([0,1) \smallsetminus C) \cup C$

$C = \{ \frac{1}{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$

$[0,1] = ([0,1) \smallsetminus C ) \cup \{ \frac{1}{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=2}$

Then $\varphi(x) = {x, x\in[0,1]} \smallsetminus \{ x_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1} $.

$\varphi(x_{n}) = x_{n+1}$ if $x_{n} = \frac{1}{n}.$
This is equivalent to the bijection $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, with $f(x) = x+1$. This is the same as the Hilbert Hotel.

*I do not understand this proof at all; namely since I do not understand (1) and since so little detail is given. Any exposition in more detail of (2) and (1) would be most helpful.*

Comment: Please ask for only one proof explanation per post.  Else, the question becomes too broad.  And in each of the separate questions, please specify in greater detail than you do here, what it is you do not understand, step by step, if necessary.

Comment: Are you saying you do not know what "disjoint sets" means?

Comment: @user247327 I know what disjoint sets are unsure of what a 'disjoint union' is, as was stated in the lecture. I am also unsure as to why we may assume this.

Comment: Your post contains some conflatons. For example, you start by saying you wanted to understand a proof that infinite subsets of countable sets are countable, but the proof you worked through was instead of the fact that an infinite set's union with a countable set is of the same cardinality as the original. Then you say the union is assumed disjoint; I'm pretty sure you meant intersection. Next, you don't define $C$.

Comment: @J.G. I am sure what you say is correct, and it is why I do not understand the proof as stated in the lecture. The lecturer has a habit of omitting on the board the words in between his statements and is also foreign so sometimes states things in confusing syntax such that the result of my copied version of the proof is very difficult to understand.

Comment: @J.G. You did however, alert to me a mistake where I included a reference to the wrong Theorem. Thank you. This has been edited.

Comment: Oh, okay.  I can see that.  A disjoint union simply means that it is a union of two disjoint sets.  And we may assume that because if A and B are not disjoint, we can replace A by $A- A\cap B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately both proofs are so muddled in their given state, be it due to your lecturer's poor exposition or your not copying down every detail he presented, that I'm not sure which proof was intended. So instead of filling in the gaps, I'll start over.

For theorem 1 $A\cup B=A\cup (B\backslash A)$, so without loss of generality $A\cap B=\emptyset$. If $A\backslash B$ is finite, say of size $n$, $A\cup B=(A\backslash B)\cup B$ is countable; just add $n$ elements to the front of an enumeration of $B$. If on the other hand $A\backslash B$ is infinite, it has a countable subset, say $D$. Then $A\cup B=(A\backslash D)\cup (D\cup B)$. Replacing the $n$th element of $D$ in $A\backslash D$ with the $n$th element of $D\cup B$ (for some enumeration of each), $A\cup B$ has an immediate bijection with $A$. So the theorem reduces to $D\cup B$ being countable, which follows from alternating elements of $D$ and $B$.

Theorem 2 is the special case of theorem 1 with $A=[0,\,1),\,B=\{ 1\}$.